# ALTER TABLE with Large number of rows

Tags: mysql

I have an sales table with millions of records and I want to extend it with a new field. I know ALTER TABLE would certainly lead never ending process. Is there a faster way to do this?

Comment: create separate temp table with new column and then migrate data from your old table to new one then drop old and rename new table this will be faster than altering table

Comment: Great! But how? Anyway will try that

Comment: Check Optimizing ALTER TABLE statements in: http://www.cocomore.com/blog/mysql-query-optimization

Comment: Thanks for the updates: I found this too: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/optimizing-innodb-bulk-data-loading.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create table TEMP_TABLE WITH similer to your old table with additional column

```
INSERT INTO TAMP_TABLE (SELECT * FROM TABLE);

DROP TABLE OLD_TABLE;

RENAME TABLE TEMP_TABLE TO OLD_TABLE_NAME;
```